# Graph coloring to minimize maximum number of colors along paths

Tags: co.combinatorics, algorithms, graph-colorings

Given a graph $G$ and a pair of source-destination nodes $s$ and $t$. Each node in $G$ is to be colored. Let $C_i$ denote the available color set for node $i$. Under a coloring scheme $A$, for any $s-t$ path $p$, let $\lambda(p)$ denote the number of colors used to color the nodes in $p$ under $A$. We seek a coloring scheme that maximize $\min_{p\in P} \lambda(p)$, where $P$ denotes the set of all $s-t$ paths.

Comment: If there is no restriction on a coloring (e.g., shouldn't it be proper?), then the answer is the minimum of the number of colors and the length of the shortest $s-t$ path: just assign a color to each distance from $s$.

Comment: Thank you Ilya. Your answer holds if there are sufficient number of colors. I am more interested in the non-trivial case of limited number of colors (i.e., < path length). The coloring does not have to be proper.

Comment: in this case my coloring (of the neighborhood of $s$ with corresponding radius) already ensures that each path contains all colors.

Comment: Yes Ilya, but that is not necessarily optimal. I suppose the problem is NP-hard, but fail to figure out how to design approximation algorithms.

Comment: why it is not optimal? How can the number of cllors in the path exceed the total nimber of colors?

Comment: I forgot to put the constraint that each node can only choose a subset of colors. I have revised the problem. Pls check the revised formulation.